# Accessing column in junction table in GORM

Tags: go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I have three tables `users`, `todos` and `user_todos`:

```go
type User struct {
  ID    uint64
  Email string
  Todos []Todo `gorm:"many2many:user_todos"`
}

type Todo struct {
  ID    uint64
  Title string
}

type UserTodos struct {
  UserID uint64
  TodoID uint64
  Done   bool
}
```

Now I want to get all users with all todos. `db.Preload("Todos").Find(&users)` does the trick for that.

But what if I want to get all todos and see if they are already done by the user?

I tried to create a SQL view `checked_todos` which joins the `user_todos` table and exchange the `Todos` attribute in the `User` struct with a `CheckedTodo`, which just extends `Todo` with a boolean field. Preloading never access the right table.

Couldn't find any hints in the GORM documentation how to access the columns in the junction table.

Comment: Have you tried using a Gorm [join](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins)?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve what you want with [custom preloading](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Custom-Preloading-SQL). Two options you might want to try:

**Option 1**

```
db.Preload("Todos", func(grm *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
   return grm.Where("user_todos.done = 1")
}).Find(&users)
```

**Option 2**

```
db.Preload("Todos", func(grm *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
   return grm.Joins("INNER JOIN user_todos ON user_todos.todo_id = todos.id AND user_todos.done = 1")
}).Find(&users)
```